# How to sign Android app bundle via jenkins android signing plugin?

Tags: android, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I use jenkins to build and sign my android app apks and everything has worked fine there so far. Now we are going to migrate to the new android app bundle delivery format but now I have no idea how can I make the android signing plugin sign the generated app bundle. Any help?